# What materials would be appropriate for pool parts (chlorine & UV exposure) using SLA or FDM?

Tags: sla, filament-choice

I've got a printer on the way later this year that's supposed to be able to do both FDM and SLA (with the appropriate accessories). I'm interested in printing some parts for swimming pools (the types that generally cost fifty cents to make, but with markup and shipping end up costing thirty or more dollars).

I need to find a material that can withstand exposure to chlorine (up to 15ppm for the rare nuclear shock) and UV from the sun, hopefully for several years.

I think that I'd prefer an FDM filament initially in order to test, but understand that FDM processes may require more post-processing in order to keep water from penetrating layers.

What are some other considerations that I should be aware of? Having a white color would be preferable, but if it's available in other colors and would be suitable, it might be fun to make some different colored eyeball fittings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you thought about using ASA filament? ASA filament is very strong. ASA filament is similar to ABS filament (if you have ever worked with that). When contrasting it to ABS filament, ASA has a higher resistance against UV and chemical exposure. It will also have no problem with the water. Both ASA and ABS filament print at about the same temperatures.

Here are some links that might be helpful :

- [UV-Resistant ASA Filament: Properties, How to Use, and Best Brands](https://3dinsider.com/asa-filament/)
- [Want to Use ABS in Hot Sun? We Compare ABS vs ASA Filaments](https://rigid.ink/blogs/news/175845063-the-difference-between-abs-and-asa)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! Are you in any way affiliated with the link you provided? You should state one way or the other on it so it doesn't come across as spam.

Comment: I am not affiliated with the link provided (I just think that it is good a good overview). But, you are right. I will update the answer

Comment: That does indeed look like a good option. Especially since it can also be vapor smoothed with acetone like ABS to reduce the porosity and surface area.